# Get Alert when Balls turn red and how to change the canvas outline

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to get alert when any of the balls turn red. Every time when the balls turn red, alert should come. Anyone can you help me out to get this thing?
And i want the canvas outline stroke as black color. How to do that? I tried adding > canvas.stokestyle also but it not showing anything.

```js
function getBall(xVal, yVal, dxVal, dyVal, rVal, colorVal) {
  var ball = {
    x: xVal,
    y: yVal,
    dx: dxVal,
    dy: dyVal,
    r: rVal,
    color: colorVal
  };
  return ball;
}

var canvas = document.getElementById("Canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8
var containerR = 150;
canvas.width = canvas.height = containerR * 2;
canvas.style["border-radius"] = containerR + "px";


var balls = [
  getBall(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height - 30, 2, 2, 8, "#32CD32"),
  getBall(canvas.width / 3, canvas.height - 50, 2, 2, 8, "#32CD32"),
  getBall(canvas.width / 4, canvas.height - 60, 2, 2, 8, "#32CD32"),
  getBall(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 5, 2, 2, 8, "#32CD32")
];

function drawBall(curBall) {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(curBall.x, curBall.y, curBall.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = curBall.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

function updatePos(curBall) {
  curBall.x += curBall.dx;
  curBall.y += curBall.dy;
  var dx = curBall.x - containerR;
  var dy = curBall.y - containerR;

  if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - curBall.r) {
    var v = Math.sqrt(curBall.dx * curBall.dx + curBall.dy * curBall.dy);

    var angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
    var oldAngle = Math.atan2(-curBall.dy, curBall.dx);

    var newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
    curBall.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
    curBall.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);
  }
}

function ballsMeet(b1, b2) {
  return (Math.hypot(Math.abs(b1.x - b2.x), Math.abs(b1.y - b2.y)) < (b1.r + b2.r))
}

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

  for (var i = 0; i < balls.length; i++) {
    drawBall(balls[i])
    updatePos(balls[i])

    meet = false
    for (var j = 0; j < balls.length; j++) {
      if (ballsMeet(balls[i], balls[j]) && i != j) {
        meet = true
        balls[j].color = "red"
        break
      }
    }
    balls[i].color = (meet) ? "red" : "green"

  }
  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

draw();
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<html>
<canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
<div id="x"></div>
<div id="y"></div>
<div id="dx"></div>
<div id="dy"></div>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Don't use `alert()` when working with RequestAnimationFrame
- Don't color balls inside `draw` (BTW call it `engine` since it's a RAF recursion), use the `drawBall` instead.
- Given the above, on collision, set the ball property `collider` to be the colliding ball - and paint accordingly inside `drawBall` - that way you can restore to the original color once the ball exits collision: `ctx.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;`
- You could use CSS `radius` and `box-shadow` on the CANVAS element

```js
const ctx = document.getElementById("Canvas").getContext("2d");
const containerR = 90;
const size = containerR * 2
ctx.canvas.width = ctx.canvas.height = size;
ctx.globalAlpha = 0.8

const getBall = (x, y, dx, dy, r, color) => ({x, y, dx, dy, r, color});

const balls = [
  getBall(size / 2, size - 30, 1, 1, 30, "Blue"),
  getBall(size / 3, size - 50, 1, 1, 20, "Yellow"),
  getBall(size / 4, size - 60, 1, 1, 10, "Fuchsia"),
  getBall(size / 2, size / 5,  1, 1, 8,  "Green"),
];

const drawBall = (ball) => {
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(ball.x, ball.y, ball.r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
  ctx.fillStyle = ball.collider ? "red" : ball.color;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.closePath();
}

const updatePos = (ball) => {

  ball.x += ball.dx;
  ball.y += ball.dy;
  const dx = ball.x - containerR;
  const dy = ball.y - containerR;

  if (Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy) >= containerR - ball.r) {
    const v = Math.sqrt(ball.dx * ball.dx + ball.dy * ball.dy);
    const angleToCollisionPoint = Math.atan2(-dy, dx);
    const oldAngle = Math.atan2(-ball.dy, ball.dx);
    const newAngle = 2 * angleToCollisionPoint - oldAngle;
    ball.dx = -v * Math.cos(newAngle);
    ball.dy = v * Math.sin(newAngle);
  }
}

const collides = (a, b) => (Math.hypot(Math.abs(a.x - b.x), Math.abs(a.y - b.y)) < (a.r + b.r));

function engine() {
  console.clear(); // Clear console test messages
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);

  balls.forEach((a, ai) => {
    a.collider = undefined;
    
    balls.forEach((b, bi) => {
      if (bi === ai) return; // Don't look at self
      if (collides(a, b)) a.collider = b; // Store the colliding B ball
    });
    
    if (a.collider) { // If ball has a collider:
      console.log(`${a.color[0]} → ← ${a.collider.color[0]}`);
    }
    
    updatePos(a);
    drawBall(a);
  });

  requestAnimationFrame(engine);
}

engine();
```

```css
canvas {
  background: #eee;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 4px #000;
}
```

```html
<canvas id="Canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: C. Bulijan Thanks for your help...i need to show it as alert like pop up windows when the ball collide with another..how to do that?

Comment: @Anonymous seemed obvious, in the same place where you see the console logging things, in the same spot place your alert box. _ That's not the best idea though, since the alert will run again and again for every frame a collision is still active. You'll get into problems by using alert. Happy learning.

Comment: C.Bulijan You was right..if i add alert box it is creating problem...is there any other way to get the alert kind of thing in main window itself? Please give me a suggestion

Comment: Use a DIV element, and instead of doing `console.log("blah");` use `myDiv.textContent = "blah"` - Not sure why you need that and for what purpose though....

Comment: When i use DIV element the balls are get disappeared. Can you be more specific or can you add code snippet

Comment: @Anonymous Look at the provided code. Remove a DIV text where I use `console.clear()` and add the new text to the DIV where I use `console.log()`.  
If you don't know how to create a DIV inside HTML, and how to target it using JS, you should do a quick Google search. Basically it's `someDivOfMine.textClntent = ""` for clearing and `someDivOfMine.textClntent = "whatever"` to add a text.... But that's really basic JS stuff we're talking about here.

Comment: @Rolo C.Bulijan Yes it worked i am newbie to java script... i really understand what you are telling...Any way thanks for the help